# how to write different string in a file with specific format in python

Tags: python, string, format, output

I would like to write some string in a text file as header of my dataframe.

I have tried to use the myfile().format() method because it work very well with float number and formatting. However, it seems to working with me. This is my code:

```py
MyFile=open('./OUTPUT/output.dat','w')
MyFile.write('{}{}').format('date',';')
MyFile.close()
```

I have tried different options. I get the following error:  'int' object has no attribute 'format'

while I was expecting to have in my file "date;"
Thanks for any kind of help

Answer (score 1):

You are applying the `format` in the wrong place.

The `format` is a string method, and you are applying it to the `write` function result. Change it to:

```
MyFile=open('./OUTPUT/output.dat','w')
MyFile.write('{}{}'.format('date',';'))
MyFile.close()
```

I hope it helps.